# How to BOTH send & receive continously via UDP and post-process datagrams on both ends (using the same socket?)

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, udp

This is an issue mainly due to my inexperience with winsock, sockets, UDP, and programming in general.  There are a lot of questions/answers posted related to this issue, but I'm been unable to sift through them due to my poor understanding of winsock, etc., to grasp how to resolve my issue.

Problem.
I currently have a UDP connection running (continously), correctly, through a C++ application and C# script running in a Unity application.  Currently, the C++ application convert position data information from an external haptic device into a simple string and sends that datagram via UDP to the unity application.  The Unity script then converts the simple string back into relevant information and is used to control objects within the Unity gamespace.  This works fine, but mainly because I have been able to find scripts online which only needed a little editing and adjusting to work for my specific application.  What I now need to do is to send datagrams from the Unity application to the C++ application (the reverse of what I am currently doing) to provide haptic feedback to the haptic devices when the gameobject interacts with colliders in the Unity gamespace.  I have the data that I want to send available when contact with the colliders is made (currently prints via Debug.Log), but I don't know how to properly use the winsock Sentto and Recvfrom functions to have the C++ application actively listening (not just sending) and the Unity application actively sending (not just listening).

I will continue to look through the questions/solutions already posted to see if I can figure it out, but in the meantime if anyone can provide some assistance I would greatly appreciate it.  The relevant portions of the code that I am using are posted below:

This script is attached to my gameobject in Unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using UnityEngine.Serialization;

public class TestUDPConnection : MonoBehaviour
{

    private const int listenPort = 11000;
    private UdpClient listener;
    private IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint;

    public static string currentUDPData;
    private Thread listenerThread;
    public bool inputSignal = false;

    //bool to fix unity crash
    public int fixMe = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        // Creat a new thread for receiving UDP messages
        listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UDPReceive));
        listenerThread.Name = "UDP Receiving Thread";
        listenerThread.IsBackground = true; // run thread in background
        listenerThread.Start();
    }

    // Thread for receiving UDP input
    public void UDPReceive()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start receiving UDP.");

        listener = new UdpClient(listenPort); // Initializes and BINDS directly (this is an overload of the UdpClient function, or to be precise the Constructor)
        while (fixMe > 0) {
            try {
                // Opening udpclient listener on port
                Debug.Log("Listening to port: " + listenPort);

                // Receive bytes
                remoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0); // Initializes the Endpoint with the correct Port and any IP address (UDP is connectionless the receiver doesn't need any IP address)
                byte[] receiveBytes = listener.Receive(ref remoteIpEndPoint);

                // Encode bytes to string (with UTF8 or ASCII Encoding)
                currentUDPData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                try {
//code is parsed here

                } catch (Exception parseError) {
                    Debug.Log("Parsing didn't work: " + parseError.ToString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.Log("Something went wrong: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("Stop receiving UDP.");

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        // Executed when BACKSPACE key hit
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("backspace")) {
                DestroyObject(gameObject);
                fixMe = 0;
    }
}
    // Executed when object gets destroyed
    void OnDisable()
    {
        if (listenerThread != null) {
            listenerThread.Abort();
        }
        listener.Close();
        Debug.Log("UDP receiver closed");
        fixMe = 0;
    }
}
```

This is script that I have in my C++ application (there is more code in the script that deals with the haptic device, but this portion pertains to the UDP communication):

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

// Link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int iResult;
WSADATA wsaData;

SOCKET SendSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
sockaddr_in RecvAddr;

unsigned short Port = 11000; //port communicated through

char SendBuf[1024]; //message variable
int BufLen = 1024; //max length of buffer

int main()
{
// Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        //return 1;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------
    // Create a socket for sending data
    SendSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (SendSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        //return 1;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    // Set up the RecvAddr structure with the IP address of
    // the receiver (in this example case "192.168.1.1")
    // and the specified port number.
    RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    RecvAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    //InetPton(AF_INET, _T("127.0.0.1"), &RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    //---------------------------------------------
    // Clean up and quit.
    //wprintf(L"Exiting.\n");
    //WSACleanup();
    //return 0;

//the udp communication, data parsing, etc., is contained within this loop:
// main haptic simulation loop
    while (simulationRunning)
{
//script here for various stuff...
//taking in position values of haptic device in different variables
//converting them to strings
//adding them to the pBuffer that is sent through the UDP pipeline via:

iResult = sendto(SendSocket,
                    pBuffer, nStrSize + 1, 0, (SOCKADDR *)& RecvAddr, sizeof(RecvAddr));
                if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    wprintf(L"sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    closesocket(SendSocket);
                    WSACleanup();
                    //return 1;
                }
    }
```

So, basically, I'd like to implement the reverse of what is happening in each code (i.e., sending data in the C# Unity script and receiving data in the C++ application script).  From what I've read, you can send/receive on the same socket so it seems that it might be simple to add a few lines to my C++ simulation loop which includes the recvfrom function, and some simple copy and paste of my c++ loop into the C# script (with few adjustments) to get the data sent as well.  I'll be reading more and trying different code see about to getting it working in the meantime.  Thanks ahead of time for any assistance that you can provide!

Comment: one thing to remember udp does not guarantee delivery, and is therefore in effect not designed to be a bidirectional communication tool. TCP is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment BugFinder.  The choice of UDP over TCP was made to maximizing communication speed and minimizing processing overhead costs.  I need to simulate movement and haptic feedback while running graphical 3D environments and was informed that UDP would provide better results for my specific application.

Comment: Maybe, but if you're trying to simulate movement and haptic feedback, you surely require all parts to get there, and more over in order. UDP guarantees none of that.  UDP is broadcast and forget, tcp is more like a phone call, it connects, it talks to you, you grunt to say you got it..

Comment: all the working exmaples I've seen have used different sockets for send and recieve

Comment: @BugFinder, again thanks for your attention.  Since UDP is correctly working very well (one-way) I'd like to continue with it if it is possible to get it working both ways.

Comment: @zambari.  Thanks for the input.  I've been reviewing the microsoft docs for recvfrom function and saw: "If no incoming data is available at the socket, the recvfrom function blocks and waits for data to arrive according to the blocking rules defined for WSARecv with the MSG_PARTIAL flag not set unless the socket is nonblocking. In this case, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned with the error code set to WSAEWOULDBLOCK. The select, WSAAsyncSelect, or WSAEventSelect can be used to determine when more data arrives."  So, I'm thinking maybe I can run two threads to send/receive using same socket?

Comment: why can't you just use two sockets?

Comment: Actually, I don't have a reason why I can't.  I've only been suggesting the one socket based on what I've been reading.  I'm just assuming that one socket open (that can send/receive) would be more efficient than having two open.

Comment: This is one of the answers which I have read which says that read/send should be available on one socket, and this one also actually says that using one socket is the preferred method over using two sockets for send/receive (see part 2 of Peter Duniho's Answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625793/udp-send-and-receive-socket-behavior

Comment: I still don't have a working solution, but I am in the process of running two threads (one for sending, one for receiving) under the same socket.  I'll update if I get this working.  Also, I plan on building a a very simple c++ application that will send and receive (and open two instances of it for testing) and then a Unity application that will do the same.  If I get those working, then hopefully I will have learned winsock, etc., enough to do what I want for my specific work in and out of Unity.  I'll update but please continue with suggestions if you have any.  Thanks!

Comment: @zambari: Using two sockets doesn’t reduce the central difficulty of interleaving the sends and receives.

Comment: Been on holiday for a few days.  Since back, I've been working on different aspects of the project to fix performance issues, but I'll go back to working on this issue in the next day or so and I'll update then.  Thanks again for the comments so far, everyone.